# Parsec_Compilation_WorkerGroup_Error

Tags: benchmarking, parsec

```
WorkerGroup.h:88:5: error: looser throw specifier for 'virtual threads::WorkerGroup::~WorkerGroup() throw (threads::CondException, threads::MutexException)'
   88 |     ~WorkerGroup();
      |     ^
```

I tried Compiling parsec benchmark this still keeps showing.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `-std=g++98` in CXXFLAGS in gcc.bldconf

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).